# How to change style/design of AppShortcuts in Shortcuts App (tiles vs circle group)

Tags: iso, appintents, app-shortcut

Addind the `AppIntent` of my app as `AppShortcuts` to the Shortcuts Apps was easy. This only required an `AppShortcutsProvider`. However, I am confused how the AppShortcuts are shown in the Shortcuts App. It seems that there are different styles as one can see on this picture.

[image]

- The `AppShortcuts` of some apps are shown as tiles
- While shortcuts from other apps are shown as collection as circle icons
- Some "circle collection" use a default gray background with blue icons
- Others color or even gradient backgrounds with white icons

The only thing I found that might be related to the design is the `shortcutTileColor` property in the `AppShortcutsProvider`. However using/changing this property has no effect on how my app's shortcus are shown: On the default gray background / blue icon.

Among the different apps on my devices I cannot see any logic which shortcuts are shown as tiles and which as circle icons. Additionally third party apps use colored background (s. Gola for example on the screenshot) or gradients. So there there has to be a way to change this. But how?

Comment: having exact same issue. Moreover, it used to work when I started developing my shortcuts, but then it just stopped responding to any changes in shortcutTileColor